# railsで子テーブルの値をviewから使える方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。

現在開発しているものには４つのモデルがあります。
これらを各自A, B, C, Dだとした時にこれらの関係は
BがAを参照、CがBを参照、DがCを参照しています。
私がしたいのはAテーブルをviewでリストに表示する時にカラムを一個追加し、
Aの各IDが持っているDを全部カウントした数値を表示させたいんです。
どうしたらAのリストで各行が持っているDをカウントして表示できるか教えてください。

Comment: A,B,Cだと名前がわかりづらいのと、「参照」の意味が明確でないので、具体的なモデルのコードを記載してください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ModelA
  has_many :model_bs
end  

class ModelB 
  belongs_to :model_a
  has_many :model_cs
end

class ModelC
  belongs_to :model_b
  has_many :model_ds
end

class ModelD
  belongs_to :model_c
end
```

ということでしょうか？
色々やりようはあると思いますが、 model_a の id を キーにした hash に、カウントを保存して使う。
などはどうでしょうか？

コントローラで、ハッシュを作り

```
model_a_list = ModelA.all
model_a_ids_model_d_sizes = ModelD.joins(model_c: :model_b).group("model_bs.model_a_id").count
```

view で呼び出す、とかです。

```
- model_a_list do | model_a |
  = model_a_ids_model_d_sizes[model_a.id]
```

他には、includes して array のサイズを測る、とかもあると思います。

```
model_a_list = ModelA.includes(model_bs: { model_cs: :model_ds }).all

- model_a_list do | model_a |
  = model_a.flat_map(&:model_bs).flat_map(&:model_cs).flat_map(&:model_ds).size
```

のような感じです。

実際に動くかは確認していないです。スミマセン。